# failed to initialize logging driver: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1514: connect: connection refused

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, driver, kibana, fluentd

jeeu@DESKTOP-C6RMAI6:/mnt/d/EFK4/elasticsearch-2.1.1$ docker run --name kibana -e ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://192.168.49.1:9200 -p 5601:5601 -d kibana:4.1.4

3fdfacce49c6fd70e697570304edf65d1cf534fc794863ab1cf9e26d3f287e8d

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:24224:

connect: connection refused.

Comment: you should use the name of the service if you are using docker-compose